# Showing the double commutant of the image of GNS representation is a factor provided uniqueness of a tracial state.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra with an identity. If $A$ has a **unique** tracial state $\varphi:A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$  i.e. $\varphi(ab) = \varphi(ba)$, $\varphi(x^*x) \geq 0$, and $\varphi(1) = 1$. I am trying to show that the double commutant of the image of GNS representation for $\varphi$ is a factor i.e. $Z((\pi_\varphi(A))'') = \mathbb{C}I$.

Suppose that $Z((\pi_\varphi(A))'')$ is not a factor. There exists a nontrivial projection in $Z((\pi_\varphi(A))'')$ since $\mathbb{C}I$ is proper to $Z((\pi_\varphi(A))'')$ and using the fact the double commutant of projections in $Z(M)$ equals $Z(M)$. I am having trouble constructing tracial state to contradict the uniqueness. I know if I find a cyclic vector $\xi$ (maybe the trivial i.e. $1 + N_\varphi$), then I can construct at least a state $$\phi(a) = \langle \pi_\varphi(a)\xi, \xi \rangle$$ then $\phi$ is a state and maybe I can just it is tracial.

Comment: Note that $\pi_\varphi(A)’’$ is a finite vNa since it admits a normal faithful tracial state given by $x \mapsto \langle x \xi_\varphi, \xi_\varphi \rangle$. If it is not a factor, then it admits multiple normal tracial states given by the composition of the center-valued trace with different states on the center, contradicting the uniqueness of the trace of $A$.

Comment: A more direct argument is that, for different $f \in L^1(\mathcal{Z}(\pi_\varphi(A)’’))$, the tracial states on $A$ given by $x \mapsto \langle x \hat{f}, \hat{f} \rangle$ are different.

Comment: The time for editing my previous comment has passed, but I just realized I mistyped a few things. It should be $f \in L^2(\mathcal{Z}(\pi_\varphi(A)''))$ with $\|f\|_2 = 1$ instead of $L^1$. But the point is the same.

Comment: @DavidGao Thanks for both the direct approach and the contradiction!

Comment: @DavidGao I understand the direct approach. For the contradiction approach, from reading Takesaki I was able to get to the unique center valued trace part. Since $Z(\pi_\varphi(A)'')$ is nontrivial, speculating it seems that there should be more than 1 state defined on it. Is it straightforward to construct these states?

Comment: Any nontrivial $C^\ast$-algebra has more than one states since the dual space is spanned by states. In the abelian case there are even more than one characters (which correspond to points in the spectrum - think about the Gelfand duality). So, this is more just abstract existence. In this specific case though, if you want explicit examples of such states, just restrict the states mentioned in the direct argument to the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P\in Z(\pi_\varphi(A)'')$ be a non-trivial projection. Write $\tilde\varphi(X)=\langle X\xi_\varphi,\xi_\varphi\rangle$ the normal tracial state induced by $\varphi$. We have $\tilde\varphi(P)>0$. Choose $s\in(0,1)$ with $s\ne \tilde\varphi(P) $ and define a state $\psi$ on $A$ by
$$
\psi(a)=\frac s {\tilde\varphi(P)}\,\tilde\varphi(P \pi_\varphi(a))
+\frac {(1-s)} {\tilde\varphi(I-P)}\,\tilde\varphi((I -P) \pi_\varphi(a)).
$$
Because $\tilde\varphi$ is a trace and $P$ is central, $\psi$ is a trace. Suppose that $\psi=\varphi$. Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence such that $\pi_\varphi(a_n)\to P$. Then
$$
\tilde\varphi(P)=\lim_n\varphi(a_n)=\lim_n\psi(a_n)=s,
$$
a contradiction. So $\psi$ would be a different tracial state on $A$. The uniqueness thus implies that $Z(\pi_\varphi(A)'')$ is trivial.